# display content of json

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I'm trying to display data from a JSON I retrieve using `$.getJSON` but the following code comes back as `undefined`. I'd like to display all the data within a new row of a table for example:

```js
var sales = $.getJSON(_routes['salesInAMonthJS'], { month: "September 2016" });

$.each(sales, function(index, element) {
  console.log(element[index])
});
```

this `$.getJSON(_routes['salesInAMonthJS'], { month: "September 2016" });`

gives me back

```js
{"9":{"name":"alex lloyd","country":"Germany","antiquity":"new client","amount":"0.0 USD"},"10":{"name"
:"asdasdsadasda dasda","country":"Afghanistan","antiquity":"new client","amount":"0.0 USD"},"11":{"name"
:"Alex Lloyd","country":"American Samoa","antiquity":"new client","amount":"0.0 USD"},"12":{"name":"alex
 lloyd","country":"Aruba","antiquity":"new client","amount":"0.0 USD"},"5":{"name":"surgeon bueno","country"
:"Spain","antiquity":"renewal","amount":"2686.97 USD"}}
```

Comment: This is giving you back undefined because the `$.getJSON` method is asynchronous; the request for the data is made and does not block the execution of other code, while the program awaits a response. You need to create a callback funtion that is executed after the response is received.

Answer (score 2):

`$.getJSON` is an asynchronous operation. You are getting a promise back instead of your object that you are expecting.

try this instead:

```
 $.getJSON(_routes['salesInAMonthJS'], { month: "September 2016" }).then(
     function(d){
        console.log(d);
     });
```

`d` will contain your response data.

Comment: thanks works well, then how can I print out the contents of each key in a new html tag?

Comment: Depends on if you know the structure or if it's dynamic etc. You can look up "iterate nested json" for some ideas, but basically you can port your current `$.each(sales,function` code inside `function(d)` by changing `sales` to `d` or whatever you want to call that variable.

Answer (score 0):

As Matti Price said, $.getJSON is asynchronous. So doing a $.each right after it, won't give you anything. I would structure my code in a way similar to the following:

```
//we call this with themonth(string) as argument to get the promise back
function getSalesInMonth(themonth){
   return $.getJSON(_routes['salesInAMonthJS'], {month: themonth});
}

function renderSalesData(data){

    //here you can do whatever you cant with the data
    $.each(data, function(index, item){
       console.log(item);
    }
}

//in case of error we can show something to the user
function salesDataFail(){
    console.log("Error getting sales data");
}

//to send a request you can do:
getSalesInMonth("September 2016").then(renderSalesData, salesDataFail);
```

Check out the documentation for jQuery deferred.then here: https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/